# How do I create a form on my website that changes the meta tags on other pages on my server? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, metadata, meta-tags

How do I create a form on my website that changes the meta tags on other pages on my server? Is this possible? I am wanting to add a form that users on my website can enter data into that will change the meta data on their respective pages on my server.

i.e.  John has a bio page on my server and wants to change the meta info like page title, keywords or redirect the page entirely. John doesn't know how to edit HTML, so a simple form for him to fill out would work out nicely.

Is there a way to do this in any scripting language (HTML, JavaScript, PHP, etc?)

Comment: How is John's bio created and edited? Shouldn't this fit into the same process?

Comment: what types of pages are they?  html, php, jsp...

Answer (score 1):

How are the other pages stored?

If they are static HTML files, then you have to parse (don't use regular expressions!) the files and overwrite or create the `<meta>` tags!

Therefore you have to use a server-side language like PHP or Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Have a correspondance between a drop down selection and meta-tags, then when building the page code in your php just add the meta selected by the used in their html version.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the meta tags or specifically for a page. But you must save the meta tag values somewhere, say MySQL database and you can retrieve the data from the database and populate the meta tags